# How to change jButton value when clicked

Tags: java, list, lambda, stream, jbutton

I kept getting errors while compiling.

I have no idea how to use the list generated integers and display it into the jButtons after clicking.

```
 public static void Random ()
{
    int Rand [] = new int [49];
    for (int b = 0; b < 49; b++)
        Rand [b] = b;

    List<Integer> alist = Arrays.stream(Rand)
                                        .boxed()
                                        .map (x -> x + 1)
                                        .collect (Collectors.toList());                                 

    Collections.shuffle(alist);
}

private class HandleTextField implements ActionListener
{   
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
       for (int a = 0; a < 49; a++)
       {
        if (event.getSource() == jbArray[a]) 
        {
            //error on this line "alist cannot be resolved to a variable"
            jbArray[a].setText(alist);
        }   
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: `alist` is local to the `Random()` method, which means nothing outside of that method can use it.

Comment: Ok. How do i get the integers in the alist to display on the jbutton when clicked? I got this error "alist cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Do you want a single element of alist to display or the entire list? If you want the entire list ten how do you want it displayed(ex. comma-separated)?

Comment: @Devon Rutledge I have 49 jButtons and i want each of the jButtons to display a random integer from `alist` which is 0 to 49.

Comment: What is the event suppose to do ? You are only changing the button that trigger the event, is it expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have two problems here:

1. alist is only accessible inside your Random method because it is a local variable and it was declared there. In order to solve this problem you need to make alist declared with a larger scope [here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/local-variables-in-java/) is an explanation of local variables.
2. setText requires a String type input and alist is not a string but a list. If you want to access an element of alist then you can use alist.get(yourIndex);

   ```
   static List<Integer> alist; //is not in random method so it can be accessed by other methods
   public static void Random ()
   {
   int Rand [] = new int [49];
   for (int b = 0; b < 49; b++)
       Rand [b] = b;

   alist = Arrays.stream(Rand)
                                       .boxed()
                                       .map (x -> x + 1)
                                       .collect (Collectors.toList());                                 

   Collections.shuffle(alist);
   }


   private class HandleTextField implements ActionListener
   {   
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
          for (int a = 0; a < 49; a++)
          {
           if (event.getSource() == jbArray[a]) 
           {
               jbArray[a].setText(alist.get(a)+"");//uses only the element you want rather than all of the list
           }   
        }
      }
   }
   ```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: `Random` is a static method, so `aList` must be too.

Comment: Whoops, sorry it should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes.It works! Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

First, the generation of the list is not efficient, You create an array from 0 to 48 then use a stream to increment each values by 1 and collect the result in a `List` to shuffle it...

You can either

```
for(int i = 1; i < 50;  ++i){
    aList.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(aList);
```

Or use a `Stream` if you really wants

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 50).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Then, you need to make that list accessible from the action, you can either

- set the list a static or member variable
- return the list from the method

I prefer the second version

```
public static List<Integer> Random(){
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 50).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}
```

Perfect, you have a list accessible in the method. Now you just have to iterate each values for each button and convert the `Integer` into a `String`. I like concatenation for that.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    //Shuffle the values on each buttons
    if(event.getSource() == shuffleButton){
        List<Integer> list = random();
        for(JButton btn : jbArray){
            btn.setText("" + list.remove(0)); //Removing the item is a security to be sure the value will not be used later by mistake.
        }
    }
}
```

On one click on the button "Shuffle", every buttons present in `jbArray` will get there own values. This could be adapted to create a dynamic value length, for let's say, a dynamic number of button.

```
List<Integer> list = random(jbArray.length);
for(JButton btn : jbArray){
    btn.setText("" + list.remove(0)); //Removing the item is a security to be sure the value will not be used later by mistake.
}
```

where `random` became :

```
public static List<Integer> random(int range){
    List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, range).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    reutrn list;
}
```